# Filling empty items in a date sequence with Laravel's query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Im using Chart.js to show the number of bookings for each month. This is my query. It is working fine:

```php
$graph = DB::table('bookings')
    ->selectRaw('MONTHNAME(created_at) as month')
    ->selectRaw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%M %Y") as monthNum')
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as totalbook'))
    ->groupBy('monthNum')
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->get();
```

My problem is if there is no booking in a month then it doesnt show anything. No zero value. On the chart I get the values like

- January: 23
- February: 34
- April: 23
- May: 25
- July: 42

But March and June are not shown on the chart at all. How can I get a zero value for months where there is no booking?

Comment: I'm not sure with Laravel, but generally speaking with SQL, you can add `UNION ALL 0` to display a value that would otherwise be omitted for being null: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/790871/return-a-row-with-constants-even-if-query-comes-up-blank#bm790946, although I would consider this more a hack than a solution

Comment: Are you not going to be constraining the query by year?

Comment: im actually. DATE_FORMAT(created_At,'%M %Y') as monthNum.. i will update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL will not fill in the months that aren't available, it will simply group by what you have available and then give you those results.

What you could do is use `DatePeriod` and Laravel's `Collection` class:

```
$results = DB::table('bookings')
    ->selectRaw("DATE_FORMAT(created_At,'%Y-%m-01') as monthNum, count(*) as totalbook")
    ->orderBy('monthNum')
    ->groupBy('monthNum')
    ->get();

$results = collect($results)->keyBy('monthNum')->map(function ($item) {
    $item->monthNum = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->monthNum);

    return $item;
});

$periods = new DatePeriod($results->min('monthNum'), \Carbon\CarbonInterval::month(), $results->max('monthNum')->addMonth());

$graph = array_map(function ($period) use ($results) {

    $month = $period->format('Y-m-d');

    return (object)[
        'monthNum'  => $period->format('M Y'),
        'totalbook' => $results->has($month) ? $results->get($month)->totalbook : 0,
    ];

}, iterator_to_array($periods));
```

Please note I have updated `monthNum` in the query as it will be reformatted later.

Also, you should need to use the blade raw tags (`{!! !!}`) for this as `{{ $dat->totalbook }}` should work absolutely fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Call to a member function keyBy() on array
i got this error.my laravel version  is 5.1.46 (LTS)

Comment: @stoneshak 5.1...for some reason I thought you were on 5.4. I'll update my answer with something more appropriate. :)

Comment: thanks so much mate. works perfect except it doesnt show the data from the last month. change the datas in database to make sure but unfortunately it doesnt show the last month :(

Comment: @stoneshak I missed that, good spot! I updated my post. Adding `->addMonth()` to `$results->max('monthNum')` should do the trick :)

Comment: When there is no record i get this error.. Call to a member function addMonth() on null.. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: @stoneshak Use an `if` statement after the query to check you have results.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set zero when there are no records for counting.

Change your query something like this:

```
$graph = DB::table('bookings')
->select(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(created_at) as month'), 
         DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_At,'%M') as monthNum"),    
         DB::raw('ifnull(count(*),0) as totalbook'))
->groupBy('monthNum')
->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
->get();
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I put it exactly the same.. still works fine but unfortunately it doesn't give the zero value if there is no booking that month.

Comment: @stoneshak I think, there is problem with `count(*)`, so please try with `count(id) `it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In blade you can simply use

```
@foreach ($graph as $dat) 
    {{ $dat->totalbook ? $dat->totalbook : 0 }},
@endforeach
```

This checks if `$dat->totalbook` exists and if it does then displays the value, else will show 0.

Answer (score -1):

Use eloquent

```
Model::withCount('members')
  ->having('members_count', '>', 0)
  ->get();
```

Use query builder [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries)

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->groupBy('account_id')
                ->having('account_id', '>', 100)
                ->get();
```