# Make sql query simpler shorter ( Laravel )

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

is there any way to make these queries shorter or simpler? or maybe get the result in 1 query rather than 3.?? 
any advise appreciated

```
        $room_single = \DB::table('book_room')
        ->leftJoin('book_tour', 'book_room.bookingID', '=', 'book_tour.bookingID')
        ->where('tourdateID', '=', $id)
        ->where('roomtype','=',1)
        ->where('book_room.status','=',1)
        ->count();

    $room_double = \DB::table('book_room')
        ->leftJoin('book_tour', 'book_room.bookingID', '=', 'book_tour.bookingID')
        ->where('tourdateID', '=', $id)
        ->where('roomtype','=',2)
        ->where('book_room.status','=',1)
        ->count();

    $room_triple = \DB::table('book_room')
        ->leftJoin('book_tour', 'book_room.bookingID', '=', 'book_tour.bookingID')
        ->where('tourdateID', '=', $id)
        ->where('roomtype','=',3)
        ->where('book_room.status','=',1)
        ->count();
    $total= $room_single+($room_double*2)+($room_triple*3) ;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Can you explain please. If you just want to count booked room, you can do it in some other way.

Comment: Hi Sagar.. i m trying to count the booked rooms.. i need the number of single, double and triple rooms.. total is the total number of passenger.. it is all working with no problem. i was just wondering if there is a more elegant way than what i did

Comment: i tried that. i got the logic. for some reason it only counts the single room. it doesnt count the double or triple rooms. i will figure it out though.. i picked the first way.

Comment: okay, I think it should work but I don't know why it's getting count for only single room

Comment: am i to use the second way with foreach?

Comment: If you have no problem regarding performance and any other things, then do not change your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, since the `roomtype` column relates directly to how you would calculate the total you could just use `sum` instead of `count`:

```
$total = \DB::table('book_room')
    ->leftJoin('book_tour', 'book_room.bookingID', '=', 'book_tour.bookingID')
    ->where('tourdateID', '=', $id)
    ->where('book_room.status', '=', 1)
    ->sum('roomtype');
```

**UPDATE**

If you still need the count for each `roomtype` then you could do something like:

```
$query = \DB::table('book_room')
    ->leftJoin('book_tour', 'book_room.bookingID', '=', 'book_tour.bookingID')
    ->where('tourdateID', '=', $id)
    ->where('book_room.status', '=', 1);

$room_single = $query->newQuery()->where('roomtype', 1)->count();
$room_double = $query->newQuery()->where('roomtype', 2)->count();
$room_triple = $query->newQuery()->where('roomtype', 3)->count();
$total = $room_single + ($room_double * 2) + ($room_triple * 3);
```

Using `newQuery` means that you can reuse constraints without adding to the original.

---

Or if you don't want to make multiple queries and you want php to handle the counts

```
$rooms = \DB::table('book_room')
    ->select('roomtype')
    ->selectRaw('count(*) as room_count')
    ->leftJoin('book_tour', 'book_room.bookingID', '=', 'book_tour.bookingID')
    ->where('tourdateID', '=', $id)
    ->where('book_room.status', '=', 1)
    ->whereBetween('roomtype', [1, 3])//This is only needed if you have other room types
    ->groupBy('roomtype')
    ->orderBy('roomtype')
    ->get('roomtype');

list($room_single, $room_double, $room_triple) = $rooms->pluck('room_count')->toArray();
$total = $rooms->sum(function ($item) {
    return $item->room_count * $item->roomtype;
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: as well as $total , i also need $room_single, $room_double, room_triple.. is there an easy way with your query?

Comment: @stoneshak I've updated my answer with some more possibilities.

Comment: Thanks so much. Its great. nice and simple. do you mind looking at this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808189/how-to-get-the-record-if-count-is-zero-in-laravel

Comment: is there any way to make this Laravel 5.1 compatible ? thanks mate

Comment: @stoneshak Is it just the `$rooms->sum(...)` bit that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough contributions that is why am posting as answer.
try

```
GROUP BY roomtype
```

Then you will not need to change your roomtype.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in more simple way.

one is,

```
$query = \DB::table('book_room')
         ->leftJoin('book_tour', 'book_room.bookingID', '=', 'book_tour.bookingID')
         ->where('tourdateID', '=', $id)
         ->where('book_room.status','=',1);

$room_single = $query->where('roomtype','=',1)->count();
$room_double = $query->where('roomtype','=',2)->count();
$room_triple = $query->where('roomtype','=',3)->count();
```

And then add these as you want. This is just reducing your lines of code.

Another and better way is following.

```
$all_type = \DB::table('book_room')
            ->leftJoin('book_tour', 'book_room.bookingID', '=', 'book_tour.bookingID')
            ->where('tourdateID', '=', $id)
            ->where('book_room.status','=',1)
            ->select('roomtype',\DB::raw('COUNT(bookingID) as count'))
            ->groupBy('roomtype')
            ->get();
```

With this query you will get three count for each room type.
Hope you understand.

Comment: Your first example would only work for the `$room_single` query as the following queries would still include the where causes from the previous queries.

Comment: thanks . thats why i couldnt get it to work. let me try yours

Comment: @stoneshak okay best of luck

Comment: Great, does it help you to solve your problem then please close it